# How to parse associative type array in riak Kv?

Tags: riak, riak-search

How can I decode this JSON in Riak-solr?

```
{"policy_number":"1000067730-14","issue_date":"16/04/2016","expiry_date":"15/04/2017","discount_details":{"members":[{"member_id":"1111100018","memberName":"Ms Sonali Arora","quarters":[{"quarter_number":1,"quarter_discount":"10.0","quarter_startdate":"16/04/2016","quarter_enddate":"15/07/2016","average_steps":"222222"}]},{"member_id":"1111100019","memberName":"Ms Sonali Arora","quarters":[{"quarter_number":1,"quarter_discount":"5.0","quarter_startdate":"16/04/2016","quarter_enddate":"15/07/2016","average_steps":"205222"},{"quarter_number":2,"quarter_discount":"0.4","quarter_startdate":"16/07/2016","quarter_enddate":"13/10/2016","average_steps":"3500"}]}]},"email":"garimagauri@gmail.com","mobile":"9958791166","proposerName":"Ms Sonali Arora"}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the JSON extractor at http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.0/using/reference/search/#extractors

Comment: I am able to index  ALL Linear data but remaining data is not able for indexing how we do that,,,,explain   {"policy_number":"1000067730-14","issue_date":"16/04/2016","expiry_date":"15/04/2017","email":"garimagauri@gmail.com","mobile":"9958791166","proposerName":"Ms Sonali Arora"}

Comment: The [schema page](https://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.0.0/developing/usage/search-schemas/) has an example of a schema that indexes fields in an object using the JSON extractor.  What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: I am not able to make indexing of Riak bucket, after creating index by use of developed schema and assign to the bucket as well as search index. its making index.

Comment: hii all, now i am able to make indexing of following json.